# Subcription outside OnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two child components and i want pass data between them, to do this i use service.

In service i have

```
 headerObject = new Subject<HeaderObject>();
```

In first component i have method

```
  onClick() {
    this.listImage = this.imageService.getImages();
    let headers = new HeaderObject();
    headers.file = this.listImage[0].data;
    this.documentService.getOcrDocument(headers).subscribe(res => {
    headers = res;
    this.ocrService.headerObject.next(headers);
  })
```

In second component

```
   headerSubcribed: HeaderObject;
   private headerSubscription: Subscription;

   ngOnInit() {
     this.headerSubscription = 
     this.ocrService.headerObject.subscribe((ocrHeader: HeaderObject) => {
     this.headerSubcribed = ocrHeader;
   }
```

But ngOnInit() only once after render view i want to move this code to outside ngOnit and exeute it but i don't know how ? Some tips how execute that code? I set breakpoint at next() method that emit value but later method subscribe isn't execute? What could I do wrong?

Comment: put inside constructor

Comment: @Thabung if next question emit value that subcribe method execute even constructor that is execute at the begining. How to execute this snippet of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts which you observable/subscribe

**Observing something and notifying.**
In your service, you have a `Subject` type variable and you are pushing values to it by calling next(). when this method called, it notifies all the observers means who ever is subscribing it.

**listening to the observer and do action**
When you listen to an observer, you get an update when they change the value. It does not matter if you put your subscription in onNginit or constructor, if the code is there, it will notify you when there is a change into it.

You can also explore `BevavourSubject` if it fits to your situation.

Comment: i push to next() method value from get rest method but subscription is not notify why why this is happening?